# Constructing delegates that require each other

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm trying to define two delegates that reference each other, but I'm not sure what the most effective way to do that is. I'd like to be able to do it without any implicitly captured closures.

I've got something that looks a little like this:

```
Func<A, C> AtoC = null;
Func<B, C> BtoC = delegate(B b_in)
{
   //... uses some variables scoped to the outer method
   return b_in.getC() ?? AtoC( b_in.getA() );
}
AtoC  = delegate(A a_in)
{
   //... uses some variables scoped to the outer method
   return a_in.getC() ?? BtoC( a_in.getB() );
}

C final = AtoC(someA);
```

Of course, the real logic is more complicated, but as you can see each delegate references the other, and also has implicitly captured closure.

I'd like to be able to make the construction of these delegates more explicit by having a factory create them using the "variables scoped to the outer method":

```
Func<A, C> AtoC = null;
Func<B, C> BtoC = MakeFunctionBtoC(someVariables, AtoC)
Func<A, C> AtoC = MakeFunctionAtoC(someVariables, BtoC)
C final = AtoC(someA);

//Elsewhere...
Func<B, C> MakeFunctionBtoC(someVariables, Func<A, C> AtoC)
{
    return delegate(B b_in)
    {
       //... uses someVariables
       return b_in.getC() ?? AtoC( b_in.getA() );
    }
}
```

Thus explicitly capturing the 'someVariables' that I wish to construct the delegate with. The problem is that using this method, the function `AtoC` that gets passed to the `BtoC` factory is null when the method is called, and that null value is copied, so even when the delegate is called later on, the function `AtoC` is never defined (as it is in the former case).

Is there a way that I can use factory methods for the delegates while still having them depend on each other?

Comment: On a tangent, this strategy is also useful for an anonymous method that needs to reference *itself*.  That is a case of circular references where the size of the circle is 1, not 2 as it is here.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the solution that you have that uses closures?  What are you trying to gain by avoiding closures?

Comment: I think when it boils down to it, I just want my code to be more modular. These delegates are actually quite complicated (a dozen lines of code), and I don't like defining functions within functions. I'd much rather be able to use factories. I'll try your wrapper suggestion.

Comment: Then make that clear in your question; you want to define the main business logic in a separate named method, rather than in an anonymous method.  You don't have any problem using closures.  That's a very different problem; one that you can use closures to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to refactor out the real business logic of these two methods into their own named methods, you can most certainly do that.  You can then use an anonymous method that closes over the delegates to actually call that named method:

```
Func<A, C> AtoC = null;
Func<B, C> BtoC = b => ConvertBToC(someVariables, AtoC);
AtoC = a => ConvertAtoC(someVariables, BtoC);
C final = AtoC(someA);
```

Now you can write `ConvertBToC` as a separate named method that can accept the `Func<A, C>` as an argument.  It allows the converting of each object to the other object to be separated from the wiring up of the two delegates with their circular reference.  Of course it doesn't avoid using closures at all; it just keeps them separated from the business logic.

If you want to actually avoid the use of closures, as your question technically asks for:

You can add another layer of indirection; creating a mutable reference type with a field of the relevant delegate type that the functions can both reference:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

Func<B, C> MakeFunctionBtoC(someVariables, Wrapper<Func<A, C>> AtoC)
{
    return delegate(B b_in)
    {
       //... uses someVariables
       return b_in.getC() ?? AtoC.Value( b_in.getA() );
    }
}
```

Of course, this is the moral equivalent of what's going on when you use closures, as you do in your first solution (and I feel the need to point out that your second solution is closing over variables as well, they're just method parameters instead of local variables).

I don't see this as in any way superior to your original solution, which seems like by far the best way to solve this problem to me.

The other option you have is to effectively just do the refactor that the compiler would otherwise do when it sees a closure, namely create a new type, create a mutable field to represent the closed over variable, and then use that instead of the closed over variable everywhere.  You're only ever really  making the code more complex by doing this instead of using a closure though.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I don't like that this changes the logic of what happens inside the delegate, but I think it's more clear than the former approach. One of my goals is to make the scope of the references these delegates use as clear as possible, since many such delegates will be created, and they're going to be invoked asynchronously.

Comment: @Alain This *doesn't* functionally change what the delegate does as compared to your original solution, which you said functioned correctly.

Comment: This worked for me. Word of warning to others, do not attempt to implement your wrapper as a `struct`. I did this at first but quickly found that `struct` instances passed as parameters are shallow copied, resulting in the `Value` reference being lost again (same as when passing it directly to the factory).

Comment: @Alain I was very explicit in my answer that it needed to be a reference type.  I stated that for a reason; it's important to what's going on.